# Link to a javascript link on another page

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

**Destination page with JS link:

dest.htm**

```
<html>
..
<a href="javascript:function(parameters);">JS LINK</a>
..
</html>
```

**Origin page:

origin.htm**

```
<html>
..
<a href="dest.htm">Destination page</a>
..
</html>
```

Currently, I am linking to the destination page. The user has to then click on the JS function link manually. Can I link to the destination page, such that, on page load, the appropriate function is initiated?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `<body onload="your_function()">` on a dest.html is enough? :)

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. But you can call the site with a special `querystring`, which can be detected by your javascript in your destination page.

**origin.htm**

```
<a href="dest.htm#foo">Destination page</a>
```

**dest.htm**

```
<script>
    if(location.hash === '#foo') {
         yourfunction();
    }
</script>
```